# only see 'welcome to nginx' when accessing site from public ip address

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

When I access my wordpress site via `localhost` or the local LAN address, everything works properly.
But when I access it from outside, like this: `http://123.123.123/` (where 123.123.123 is my public ip) I only get the `Welcome to nginx` page. However, if I access `http://123.123.123/wordpress`, I do get a wordpress page.

What could be wrong?
The following is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen   80;


        root /var/www/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name 123.123.123.123;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on a UNIX socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

How do I get started debugging this?

Comment: And have you made changes for `site_url` & `blog_url` in WordPress from `localhost` to `123.123.123.123` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your try_files has $uri as first argument, you will hit the index.html in your /var/www and that will satisfy that, so if you put the php-argument first, or go to:

```
http://123.123.123.123/index.php
```

you should see your wordpress site.

Comment: I modified the `try_files` line as follows: `try_files $uri/index.php $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;`. It does now show a wordpress page, but why is it not the home page? Which debugging tools can I use here?

Comment: For some reason index.php sends me to  "Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!"?